# Export as grease pencil SVG showing up Blank

Tags: export, grease-pencil, svg

I'm trying to export an SVG so its visible in Inscape but the SVG that I open after exporting in Inkscape is just shadows. The render looks completely fine. I followed this tutorial but cant figure out what I'm missing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ji06I_KalEw
[image]